# UMVUE for some function $\tau(\theta)$ when $f(x;\theta)=\frac{\ln(\theta)}{\theta -1} \theta^x$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, parameter-estimation

I need to find an UMVUE for some function $\tau(\theta)$ for $X_1, \dots, X_n$ random variables with $f(x;\theta)=\frac{\ln(\theta)}{\theta -1}  \theta^x$ where $x\in (0,1)$.
I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is a Sufficient and complete statistic, but I don't know which function to choose such that it turns out to be an unbiased estimator.
Any hint?

Comment: For some function or all functions? $\sum X_i$ is of course UMVUE of its expectation which you can calculate.

Comment: The exercise says some fuction $\tau(\theta)$, and I have to describe that function.
I tried to do that, but I can't see what distribution has $\sum X_i$. I tried to see what distribution it has through the moment generator function, but I couldn't see it either @StubbornAtom

Comment: $f$ is a density of a truncated exponential distribution and there does not appear to be a tractable form of the distribution of $\sum X_i$ (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/269170/119261)). So I would just find out $E_{\theta}(\overline X)=E_{\theta}(X_1)$ using the distribution of $X_1$; $\overline X$ is then UMVUE of the resulting function of $\theta$.

Comment: according to the link you put, in this case $ f $ does not seem to have the truncated exponential form  @StubbornAtom